# Web app user action logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, error-logging

I am developing an web app in asp.net which is an automation tool in which want to maintain the logs of all the activities for example user login from this ip, he clicks on this tab etc. how it is possible? any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You're question is quite vague, but have you considered using something like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) or [Webtrends](http://www.webtrends.com/)? These products offer features for showing you stats about website usage.